# Converting GET method url's to logical permanent links

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, permalinks

I have a J2EE application with a web service which goes like

```
http://servername/service?task=getFile&id=25
```

How can I convert these type of urls to

```
http://servername/service/getFile/25
http://servername/service/getFile/26
```

etc?

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: What exactly would you like to convert? The fresh new incoming HTTP requests? Or the existing links in the JSP page? And how exactly would you convert it? Redirect the "ugly" to the "friendly" one and/or forward the "friendly" to the "ugly" one?

Comment: I would like to convert fresh incoming HTTP requests. And it should forward the 'friendly' ones to 'ugly' one. I was thinking of setting up a custom error page and handle these requests there and forward to the correct urls. Will it be possible to accomplish this without redirection so that the url in addressbar remains the same?

Comment: Something similar to Stack Overflow urls...I dont see any GET requests.It appears as if there is a directory structure. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the point, you thus want to **forward** the *friendly* URL to an *unfriendly* URL (so that you don't need to change existing request parameter collecting logic of the servlet) and to **redirect** the *unfriendly* URL to an *friendly* URL (so that the *friendly* URL get reflected in the browser address bar of the client).

The best place for this is a `Filter`. To access the `HttpServletRequest`, just downcast `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest`. You can get the query string by [`getQueryString()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) and you can get the pathinfo by [`getRequestURI()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29). Here's a kickoff example:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest httpreq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String query = httpreq.getQueryString();
    if (query != null) {
        // Unfriendly URL invoked. Convert params to pathinfo and redirect.
        StringBuffer newURL = httpreq.getRequestURL();
        for (String param : query.split("&")) {
            newURL.append('/').append(param.substring(param.indexOf('=') + 1));
        }
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(newURL.toString());
    } else {
        // Friendly URL invoked. Convert pathinfo to params and forward.
        String[] parts = httpreq.getRequestURI().replace(httpreq.getContextPath(), "").split("/");
        String newURL = String.format("%s?task=%s&id=%s", parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
        httpreq.getRequestDispatcher(newURL).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

You can of course also grab the aforementioned `UrlRewriteFilter`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help...But I'm having doubts on where to implement this logic. I can add this in the Servlet, but will the request ever reach here? If I give the friendly url directly, it will only give a 404 error,right?Upon giving the friendly url, how will the control go to the servlet(that process the url) directly?After all the friendly url mimics a directory strutcure. I should use the mod_rewrite for this,no?

Comment: Filter, I said Filter. Please read the introductory text as well and not only the code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I jumped into an unnecessary conclusion.Its clear to me now. Meanwhile the UrlRewriteFilter also looks like a good solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) in order to achieve this. You will just have to write the rules for rewriting, similar to mod_rewrite. [For example](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/guide.html):

```
<rule>
    <from>^/products/([0-9]+)$</from>
    <to>/products/index.jsp?product_id=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: This is a great solution and many thanks for suggesting it! Stil, I'm going for the Filter method to get a better understanding of it and ofcourse learn by coding it.

Comment: @whoopy_whale as the name suggests this is a `Filter` as well. It is open source, so you can view its code.